# number of sigma algebras on finite sets?

Tags: measure-theory

If given some **finite** family of **finite** sets on a **finite** set $X$, can we say something about the number of $\sigma$-algebras containing that family?

I've seen plenty of examples of $\sigma$-algebras but not much about how many there actually are. For infinite cases, I've always just assumed there were infinitely many, but this may not hold true for the finite case described above?

Comment: @BLAZE: Not every question involving sets is a question about set theory.

Comment: Well, since a sigma algebra is determined by the set if contains, it is atleast bounded by $|P(P(X))|=2^{2^{|X|}}$, which shows that the number is not infinite. Infact, by closure under complements, it suffices to determine sets of size less or equal to $|X|/2$, and we can ignore the empty set, so that the bound $2^{2^{|X|/2-1}}$ is better. This fixes two axioms, the only one left being closure under union, for which the combinatorics is harder.

Answer (score 6):

You can show that every $\sigma$-algebra on a finite set is defined by a partition (and it is isomorphic to $\mathcal P(S)$, where $S$ is the defining partition).

The way you do it is by showing that if $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, then below every non-zero element, there is a minimal positive element (or an atom in the technical jargon). You can then show that the set of atoms is a partition, and that there is a canonical isomorphism between $B$ and $\mathcal P(S)$, where $S$ is the set of atoms.

So the question is how many partitions a finite set has. And the answer is not pretty in the form of [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions).

So in order to count how many $\sigma$-algebras contain a certain family of subsets, you need to ask yourself what partitions can be used to generate the family of sets. I am not aware of any "pretty" combinatorial term for this, but it can't be pretty.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila Can you please tell how to prove the arguments you used or suggest somr source where it could be found ie how to prove - 1. every sigma algebra on a finite set is defined by a partition which is isomorphic to P(S) , where S is defining partition. 2 . How to prove that below every non zero element there is a minimal positive element called atom.

Comment: The first thing follows immediately from the second, which follows immediately from the fact that every finite partial order has a minimal element.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila can you please tell how 1st will follow from 2nd

Comment: Every set in your $\sigma$-algebra is the union of the atoms below it.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila can you please suggest some source where it is proved that there exists canonical isomorphism between B and P(S) .

Comment: Where S is set of atoms.

Comment: I don't know of a source. The proof is pretty straightforward, just write it down.

Comment: Sir, I am studying measure theory and I haven't taken any course on combinatorices

Comment: I am not "sir". And this is not about combinatorics, but rather writing out the definition. I already told you, every set in a finite $\sigma$-algebra is a union of the atoms below it.