# How many $ \sigma $ algebras can be defined on a set of 4 distinct elements.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying this problem on measure theory and I don't have a clue on how to proceed. I tried using definition of $ \sigma $ algebra and forming various types of sets but could not see a pattern on how to proceed towards a formula

Question is -  How many $ \sigma $ algebra can be defined on $S= \{ a, b, c, d \}$  where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are $4$ distinct elements. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $S$ then $A$ contains minimal sets which are disjoint, and their union is $S$. It follows that the set ${\cal A}$ of such algebras is related to the set of partitions of $S$. This set has $B_4=15$ elements, whereby $B_n$ denotes the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) of $n$.

An example: Let $P:=\bigl\{\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\}\bigr\}$ be a partition of $S$. Then $P$ generates the $\sigma$-algebra of the $2^3$ unions of various elements of $P$.

Comment: I am really sorry that I am asking this doubt late ( due to illness) , but to use bell number we have to prove the statement which you gave in 1 st  two lines of proof that if A is $ /sigma $ algebra on S then A always  contains minimal sets which are disjoint and their union must be S. Can you please prove this statement. I

Comment: @user686624: See the first answer here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451976/number-of-sigma-algebras-on-finite-sets

Answer (score 1):

This is the same answer as the one given by Christian Blatter, please give him the credit, the sentences are different and the solution is an ad-hoc counting, just an alternative view.

A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on the finite set $S$ is atomic, the atoms are the minimal non-void $\mathcal F$-measurable sets, all atoms determine a partition of $S$ by subsets. Let us count all these partitions. First of all, such a partition is characterized by the cardinalities of the parts, which realize a (number) partition of $4$, the cardinality of $S$. All (number) partitions of $4$ are as follows, and we also count in each case how many different ways exist to realize it:

- $4=4$, one atom, $S$, one possibility, combinatorially $\binom 44=1$,
- $4=3+1$, two atoms of cardinalities $3,1$, there are $\binom 41=4$ choices to chose the one-element atom, this determines the complement atom,
- $4=2+2$, two atoms of cardinalities $2,2$, there are $\binom 31=3$ ways to chose the one-element atom containing $a$, this determines the complement atom, (or we may count $\binom 42=6$ possibilities for two *ordered* atoms of cardinality $2$, but exchanging the order gives the same $\sigma$-algebra, so we divide by $2$...)
- $4=2+1+1$, and the choice of the $2$-elements atom determines the composition of atoms, there are $\binom 42=6$ choices,
- $4=1+1+1+1$, one possibility...

Totally there are thus 
$$
1+4+3+6+1=15
$$
possibilities.

Comment: thank you for  really nice explanation