# A Probability of $\sigma$-Algebra: The probability of a uniformly sampled subset of the powerset being a $\sigma$-algebra on that set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-distribution

Let's say we have a finite set $S$ where $|S|=n$ and we take its powerset $X = \mathcal{P}(S)$ to generate a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{P}(X))$. From this we consider the probability space $(X, \mathcal{P}(X), \mathbb{P})$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is a [uniform probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution). **What is the probability that a uniformly sampled $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ is $\sigma$-algebra on S?**

My intuition is that the probability will vanish as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but for finite sets it should be non-zero since there exists members of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ that are measurable.

Comment: $X$ is still finite. If $P$ is uniform then all subsets of $X$ are measurable.

Comment: @copper.hat I just realized I have not stated my question correctly! Rather than 'measurable', I meant 'is $\sigma$-algebra on $S$'. I will correct that.

Comment: @Saegusa Does it help your understanding to say that not all $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ makes a $\sigma$-algebra $(S, A)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is
$$
p_n:=\frac{B_n}{2^{2^n}},
$$
where $B_n$ is the $n$-th Bell number. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451976/number-of-sigma-algebras-on-finite-sets) for details.)

---

Using Theorem 2.1 in [this paper](https://www.openu.ac.il/lists/mediaserver_documents/personalsites/tamirtassa/lp_moments.pdf),
$$
p_n\le \frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\left(\frac{0.792n}{\ln(n+1)}\right)^n\to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$.